# rearrange specific rows into columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to rearrange rows into columns in a specific way (preferably using dplyr) but I dont really know where to start with this. I am trying to create one row for each person (Bill or Bob) and have all of that persons values on one row. So far I have

```
df<-data.frame(
  Participant=c("bob1","bill1","bob2","bill2"),
  No_Photos=c(1,4,5,6)
)

res<-df %>% group_by(Participant) %>% dplyr::summarise(phot_mean=mean(No_Photos))
```

which gives me:

```
  Participant mean(No_Photos)
       (fctr)           (dbl)
1       bill1               4
2       bill2               6
3        bob1               1
4        bob2               5
```

GOAL:

```
    mean_NO_Photos_1 mean_No_Photos_2
bob   1               5
bill  4               6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(rep = extract_numeric(Participant),
              Participant = gsub("[0-9]", "", Participant)) %>% 
       group_by(Participant, rep) %>%
       summarise(mean = mean(No_Photos)) %>%
       spread(rep, mean)

Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

  Participant     1     2
        (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1        bill     4     6
2         bob     1     5
```

Comment: No problem, you can delete comments using the little x if they are unneeded

Comment: I dont want to edit your solution directly, but if you wouldnt mind changing `mean=mean(No_Photos)` to `mean=mean(phot_mean)` that would fix the issue (I updated my code to match this)